# Any practical difference between using `docker build` & `docker push` together vs. `cloud build submit` in cloud build config files?

Tags: google-cloud-build

[Google Cloud docs](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/building/build-containers) use the first code block but I'm wondering why they don't use the second one. As far as I can tell they achieve the same result. Is there any practical difference?

```
# config 1
steps:
# Build the container image
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  args: ['build', '-t', 'gcr.io/project-id/project-name','.']
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  args: ['push', 'gcr.io/project-id/project-name']
# Deploy container image to Cloud Run
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
  args: ['run', 'deploy', 'project-name', '--image', 'gcr.io/project-id/project-name', '--region', 'us-central1']
images: ['gcr.io/project-id/project-name']
```

```
# config 2
steps:
# Build the container image
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
  args: ['builds', 'submit', '--region', 'us-central1', '--tag', 'gcr.io/project-id/project-name','.']
# Deploy container image to Cloud Run
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
  args: ['run', 'deploy', 'project-name', '--image', 'gcr.io/project-id/project-name', '--region', 'us-central1']
```

I run this with `gcloud builds submit --config cloudbuild.yaml`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the second config, you call a Cloud Build from inside a Cloud Build, that means you pay twice the docker build/push process in the second config.

That time of timeline in fact

- Cloud Build 1

  - Cloud build 2
  - Docker Build
  - Docker Push
- Deploy on cloud run

In addition, the number of concurrent build are limited and with the config 2 you use 2 times more quotas.

And the result is the same (it should be slightly faster with the config 1 because you haven't a new Cloud Build to spin up)

Comment: So is the `gcloud builds submit` unnecessary in the second config since both `builds submit` and `run deploy` include a build step?